# Adding 1 second to time in JSP JSTL

Tags: java, jstl, el

What's the correct way for doing date and time arithmetic in JSP (JSTL)?

I need to add 1 second to the current date and time or to the available date and time.

Here are examples what I'm trying to do:

```
<c:set var="currentDate_time" value="${currentDate_time + ((??? 1 second????))}" />

<c:set var="new_Date_time" value="${available_Date_time + ((??? 1 second????))}" />
```

Comment: Where is `currentDate_time` defined?  Could you create a `futureDate_time` object near the creation of `currentDate_time`?  This approach keeps the JSP (view) clean of any logic.